# Eclipse run configuration for Play Framework

Tags: java, eclipse, playframework, run-configuration

I am currently trying to run a test application based on the Play framework. The project was created using the command line tool for play and then converted into an eclipse project by using

```
play eclipse
```

The documentation says that this step also created a run configuration to run the code from eclipse.
But there is no configuration created.

After pressing run, eclipse is looking for a main method that is not existing.

I also tried to launch the project from the command line using `play ~run`.
But I have included and imported a class from another project and the compiler always ends with an error saying the imported package could not be found.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`play eclipse` (or `play eclipsify` for previous versions) is only so that you can import your project in Eclipse and use the debugger, get auto-complete, etc. You're still meant to run the application from the console though.

As to the second part of your question you'd need to provide more details. What exactly do you mean by, *"I have included and imported a class from another project"*?

Answer (score 0):

The solution for the problem was, that external libraries have to be included in the /lib folder of the project as .jar-Archive. The folder was not auto-created. All libraries in this folder will be added to the build-path of play automatically.